# Google App Engine: How to Truncate string after a given number of chars

Tags: python, django, string, google-app-engine, django-templates

I am on Google App Eninge with Django template.

I want to truncate string after a given number of chars, for example,
if a string (a title of a post) is too long, "This is a long long long long title", I want to display the first few words, like this: "This is a long long ..."

I have found some Django snippets here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1259/  http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/763/

I want to know:

1. If there is a simpler solution in Google App Engine python?
2. How can I use this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1259/
   in App Engine? I believe messing source code is not a good idea.

I need to truncate the string in Django Template, not in python source code. Something like this: `{{ string|truncatesmart:50 }}`

Comment: Do you want to truncate based on characters, or words? You mention both in your question.

Comment: @Nick both are fine. I need the faster one.

Comment: You need the _faster_ one? The execution speed of a function like this is going to contribute approximately nothing to the total render time of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of the problem, it appears it's a situation which has already been specifically addressed by pure CSS. Take a look at the [`text-overflow:ellipsis`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) property, which truncates a piece of text to fit in a desired width and puts a trailing ellipsis (...) like you mentioned. I hope that'll be a far simpler solution here and you won't have to 'reinvent the wheel'.

Comment: Handy to know, but embedding, say, an entire book in a search results page is probably a bad idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function truncatesmart in the django snippet you found is pure python, and you can use it in app engine without a change.

Answer (score 1):

The Python code to truncate a string is: `string = string[:chars]` where string is the string you want to modify and chars is an integer value for the number of characters.

The snippet you link to is great and as mentioned by @voscausa can be used directly in python if your looking for something smarter than truncating at X characters.

Comment: You dont seem to get me. I need to use it in Django Template not in Python source code!